# MAUI animations in Windows are slow / stutter

Tags: c#, windows, maui

I am using MAUI animations (Windows platform) but the animations are not smooth, they stutter.

For example:

```
this.Element.TranslateTo(500, 500, 3000, null);
```

or:

```
this.Element.RotateTo(360, 3000, null);
```

I also tried custom animations with the Animation class, but the result is the same, it is not smooth.

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you awaiting these?

Comment: No, I tried to add the await but the problem remains

Comment: Did you check if this is an existing bug with maui?

Comment: I searched, but I didn't find any information about bugs

Comment: have to tested in release mode? The debug code does run quite slow at times, so to get a real feel for deployed speed, try running in release mode if you not already.